Disable the tooltip window that pops up when typing commas in Visual Studio 2022
I am writing a Tkinter GUI program in Python using Visual Studio 2022. Whenever I type a comma, a large tooltip window pops up. I'd like to disable that.

I've tried disabling the following settings:

"Auto list members" and "Parameter information" in Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages
All settings from IntelliCode
"Offer auto import completions" in Text Editor > Python > Advanced

None of these stopped that window from popping up every time. How can it be disabled?
